# Turn off magnify on scatterChart in nvd3 using rCharts, shiny, nPlot

Tags: r, nvd3.js, shiny, rcharts

I have built a scatterChart in rCharts using nvd3.js and would like to turn off the magnify feature. Is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
output$riskChart <- renderChart({
             risk <- nPlot(Return ~ Risk, group = 'Names', data = RiskData(), 
               type = "scatterChart", dom = 'riskChart', width = 1000, height=400) 
            risk$chart(size = '#! function(d){return d.Size} !#')   
            risk$chart(color = c('#c66631', '#317cc6', '#32743a', '#c4c631'),
            tooltipContent = "#!function(key, y, e, graph) {
                return '<h4>' + key + '</h4>' +
                  '<p><strong>Risk: </strong>' + y + '<br><strong>Return: </strong>' + e + '</p>';
              }!#") 
              risk$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Risk')  
              risk$yAxis(axisLabel = 'Return')  
             return(risk)
           })
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add

```
risk$chart(showControls = FALSE)
```

to turn off controls, that include magnification.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath! I was hoping that would address the tooltip issue also, but it looks like that bug is still there.